# use loadingBuilder in NetworkImage class flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I faced some problems in my flutter app when I use network image:

the image takes too much time to load.

I found the solution by adding loading Builder prosperity in the network.image widget like that :

```
Image.network( 'URL image}',
fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
loadingBuilder:(BuildContext context, Widget child,ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ?
                loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
             : null,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

This works out right now, but then I need to add the same property (loadingBuilder) with the NetworkImage class (into the BoxDecoration)

as follows:

```
image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.cover),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
```

How do I add the loadingBuilder with the NetworkImage class (in the last part of the code)?

Comment: `DecorationImage` does not support this

Comment: is there any solation i can do for that ??

Comment: in theory yes, make your custom decoration: a class that extends `Decoration`, but in practice i dont think you will like that idea

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that I used although it seems like trick.
Using 'Stack' widget, at first show loading widget and draw image widget over that.
If that, at first loading widget will be shown and after image loading completed, image will be shown over the loading widget.

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Locate loading widget
              LoadingWidget(),
              //
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.cover),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```